# VAR coefficients

Tags: estimation, vector-autoregression

Say I have a VAR(p) model without any noise (a multidimensional AR model without noise). How would I go about calculating the coefficients that are MSE optimal? Is there an extension to the Yule Walker equations for multidimensional data?

Edit: Maybe an equation like the following would help?

$\hat Y_{k+1}^{}=AY_{k} $

where any general $\ Y_{i}=[Y_{1} \ Y_{2}\ Y_{3}\ Y_{4}\ ...... \ Y_{p}]^{T} $ and I want to estimate the optimal A in MSE sense. Such a problem should fit under a Weiner filtering approach in my opinion. Would using the matrix orthogonality principle be sufficient to solve this?

Comment: Contrary to what you are implying, an AR model does contain a noise component. E.g. in an AR(1): $y_t=c+\varphi_1 y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$, it is $\varepsilon_t$. Given that, can you specify more precisely what your VAR(p) model without any noise is?

Comment: @RichardHardy I updated my question and made it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $Y_{k+1}=AY_{k}$ where any general $\ Y_{i}=[Y_{1} \ Y_{2}\ Y_{3}\ Y_{4}\ ...... \ Y_{p}]^{T} $ and I want to estimate the optimal A in MSE sense.

So you have an exact, deterministic, linear relationship. The only thing that is missing is the coefficient values in $A$. Then equation-by-equation OLS will return you exact estimates, and they will be MSE-optimal.

> I am trying to figure out a problem where this is perhaps not even $ Y_{k+1}$ but rather maybe just an estimate of it.

If you change your problem by making $Y_{k+1}$ only observable with some error while $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$ are observable without error, you get a multivariate multiple regression. There is no MSE-optimal estimator for that. If you were to restrict your attention to linear estimators and the error variance were given, it would be a form of ridge regression (a univariate case is discussed in Dave Giles' blog ["A Regression "Estimator" that Minimizes MSE"](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/10/a-regression-estimator-that-minimizes.html). But that is perhaps too restrictive.

Comment: Why is there no MSE optimal answer for that? Shouldnt the Orthogonality Principle result in a system of equations that can solve this? I have a picture of my approach but I am unsure whether a non latex solution would be appropriate on this forum.

Comment: @Harduin, I am not familiar with the orthogonality principle from before, but from a casual read it seems it might ignore estimation imprecision and so would not be directly applicable in practice. Have you checked out the blog post? It deals with these issues.

Comment: And since you are using signal processing terminology, you may be interested in learning there is [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll look into this.